# how to drag and drop the list items in list view in android

Tags: android, listview, graphics, drag-and-drop

I have a list of records in a listview that I want the user to be able to re-sort using a drag and drop method. I have seen this implemented in other apps, but I have not found a tutorial for it. It must be something that others need as well. Can anyone point me to some code for doing this?
provide me full example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android List View Drag and Drop sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort)

Comment: Why don't you use RecyclerView? It has easy implementation of drag&drop

Comment: look at this question and its answer. You will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915570/how-to-implement-dragdrop-in-listview

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is example of drag item in android list

https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView

Comment: @Ironman but this link useful to developer so that i will wrote here

Comment: Then put as `comment` not as an `answer`.